# npm works, then doesn't work with err 'are-we-there-yet'

Tags: npm, ubuntu-14.04

This issue apparently is very common. However, I can't seem to get around this issue (Ubuntu 14.04). I have tried installing directly from nodesource.com. The interesting thing is that npm --version actually works right after installing. However, it fails in a new terminal window (session). Why would I get the following error in a new session, but not the session where I performed the npm install?

*in same session as install:
npm --version
2.11.3

*in new session
npm --version
module.js:338
   throw err:
Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that after installing npm from nodesource.com, I had two installs of npm. A new session was running npm from /usr/local/bin and the other session was running from /usr/bin. I'm not sure the correct way to resolve this; however, changing the broken npm to a symlink pointing to the path of the new install worked. I'm sure the correct solution would be to delete the older npm install first, then reinstall from nodesource.

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo mv npm npm.broken
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js npm
```